# PHP if OR is the second part checked on true?

Tags: php, optimization, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

I know this must be a simple question, but I know that in PHP in a statement like this

```
if ($a && $b) { do something }
```

if $a is false PHP doesn't even check $b

Well is the same thing true about OR so

```
if ($a || $b) { do something }
```

If $a is true, does it still check $b

I know this is elementary stuff, but I can't find the answer anywhere... Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See Example 1 on the [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) page in the manual.

```
// --------------------
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());
```

Answer (score 9):

> Evaluation of logical expressions is stopped as soon as the result is known.

[logical operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: That's a user comment, not an authoritative statement- but actually it is correct though.

Comment: Couldn't find the comment you found with CTRL+F for "evaluation" ;)

Comment: I meant the comment you found in your answer. I found the one I quoted. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
function foo1() {
  echo "blub1\n";
  return true;
}

function foo2() {
  echo "blub2\n";
  return false;
}

if (foo1() || foo2()) {
  echo "end.";
}
```

$b / foo2() isnt checked.
Demo here: [codepad.org](http://codepad.org/nI4gfJQW)

Answer (score 0):

If at least one OR Operand is true, there is no need to go further and check the other operands and the whole thing will evaluate to true.

(a || b || c || d || e ||...) will be TRUE if at least one of the operands is true, thus once I found one operand to be true I do not need to check the following operands.

This logic applies everywhere, PHP, JAVA, C...

Comment: The question wasn't about logic, it was about PHP implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you know your truth tables fairly well, then you can probably figure it out yourself. As others have said, PHP will evaluate until it is certain of an outcome. In the case of OR, only one has to be true for the statement to return true. So PHP evaluates until it finds a true value. If it doesn't find one, the statement evaluates to false.

```
<?php
if(true && willGetCalled()) {}
if(false && wontGetCalled()) {}
if(true || wontGetCalled()) {}
if(false || willGetCalled()) {}
?>
```